# Adding uiTextfield in UiviewController correctly

Tags: xamarin.ios

I  am learning IOS using Xamarin. I am facing a problem of adding new `uitextfield` in my `viewcontroller`. I tried to find a solution but after 4 hours research didn't find anything.

Without adding `uitextfield`, `viewcontroller` shows all controls but when I add `uitextfield`, `viewcontroller` become blanks. Following is the uitextfield code:

```
 UITextField txtUserame = new UITextField(new CGRect(70, 130, 150, 50));
            txtUserame.Placeholder = "Username";
            txtUserame.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default;
            txtUserame.BecomeFirstResponder();
            txtUserame.VerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center;
            this.View.AddSubview(txtUserame);
```

How can I fix such behaviour?

Comment: can you show me the view controller design or code where you are adding the text field

Comment: You need post some code of your ViewController, then we can help you.